# Qu'est ce que signifie le mot "pirette" ?

Tags: vocabulaire, demande-de-mot

Dans la nouvelle "Le Passe-muraille" de Marcel Aymé j'ai trouvé un mot dont je ne connais pas le sens. Dans la traduction italienne de cette nouvelle, le mot n'est pas traduit.

Il s'agit de "**pirette**", voilà la phrase complète :

> Il prescrivit le surmenage intensif et, à raison de deux cachets par
> an, l'absorption de poudre de **pirette** tétravalente, mélange de
> farine de riz et d'hormone de centaure. Ayant absorbé un premier
> cachet, Dutilleul rangea le médicament dans un tiroir et n'y pensa
> plus.

Pouvez-vous m'expliquer ?

Comment: ... comme l'hormone de centaure, une invention que vous comprendrez quand verrez un passe-muraille :-)

Comment: Mais l'hormone de centaure c'est une invention décrie avec 2 mots qui existent : )
Vous voulez dire que le mot pirette n'existe pas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Le mot ***pirette*** existe bien puisque Marcel Aymé l'a inventé<sup>1</sup> et en a même fourni une définition précise.

En revanche, comme déjà écrit en [commentaire](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/54105/quest-ce-que-signifie-le-mot-pirette#comment115337_54105), la poudre de pirette n'existe pas puisque l'un de ses composants est imaginaire.

Pour une explication plus approfondie du Passe-muraille, voir [cette page](https://cotentinghislaine.wixsite.com/website-7/ayme-explications) de Ghislaine Cotentin d'où je tire cet extrait:

> *Pour la prescription, le lexique accentue encore la satire, d’une part parce qu’il est pour le moins curieux de proposer le « surmenage intensif » comme remède – en plus à un fonctionnaire enfermé dans la routine ! –, d’autre part par le rythme, « deux cachets par an », et la composition du médicament fourni, à la fois imaginaire, la « poudre de pirette tétravalente », et emprunté, de façon cocasse, à un être fabuleux de la mythologie, moitié homme et moitié cheval : « mélange de farine de riz et d’hormone de centaure ».*

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Le mot *pirette* existait en fait déjà en ancien français, au moins sous la forme *[pirotte](https://micmap.org/dicfro/search/dictionnaire-godefroy/pirotte)* (Jeune oie femelle, le mâle étant appelé *[piron](https://www.littre.org/definition/piron)*) et a subsisté dans certains parlers de l'ouest de la France, par exemple à Rennes : *Pirette : Petite oie, on dit aussi d'une femme indolente, c'est une pirette*, Source: *Mélange sur les langues, dialectes et patois*, 1831.</sub>

Comment: ... bel ouvrage... bientôt 150 k :-)